# Transfer AISPL account to AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to transfer my account from AISPL to AWS. This is because, I had been running my application in AISPL account till now. Now I want to add my account to an AWS organisation of my employer whose seller of record is AWS. So that my employer can take care of all the consolidated billings in USD.

Currently, adding AISPL account into AWS account organisation is not supported and shows an error response of "You can only join an organization whose Seller of Record is same as your account".

What can I do to transfer my AWS account from AISPL to AWS so that I can add my account to AWS organisation ?

Answer (score 9):

I had posted a query on AWS support for this and got the below reply.

Hello,

I understand you would like to update your AISPL account and utilize services from Amazon Web Services Inc. instead.

At this time your account utilizes services from AISPL (Amazon Internet Services Private Limited) which is the Indian AWS reseller for Indian customers.

The main difference between AWS accounts and AISPL accounts is the seller of record. AISPL accounts are administered by Amazon Internet Services Private Limited, but AWS accounts are administered by Amazon Web Services, Inc.

Accounts located in AISPL can update their account information, but will continue to be billed in INR and utilize services from AISPL. If you wish to utilize services from Amazon Web Services Inc. and update your preferred currency, then you will need to create a new AWS account.

More information can be found using the link below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/manage-account-payment-aispl.html#determine-seller

We cannot transfer an account from AISPL to AWS. Need to create a new account for this.

Comment: How do I migrate everything from my old account ( including S3 buckets, Certificates, Beanstalk instances, etc ) to my new account in a new country?

Comment: AWS Knowledge Center 

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/organizations-seller-of-record-error/

Comment: Just a rant. AISPL has completely ruined my experience. No automatic payment, which makes for a terrible cloud experience. Each time I have to log in and manually make payment. If I fall sick and go to a hospital for 2 weeks, my account is blocked. Thanks a bunch RBI